# norm 2 of matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to find two vector a and b such that
$M a=\lambda b$  with M being a real matrix of size m x n

and $\|a\|_{2}=1$,

$\|b\|_{2}=1$ and $\lambda=\|M\|_{2}$.

we know that by definition  $ \|M\|_2=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Mx\|_2\ $

and that the set $\ S^{n-1}=\big\{x\,\big|\,\|x\|_2=1\big\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\ $
is compact and that the function $\ x\mapsto\|M\|_2\ $ is continious so it must attain the supremum but i can't quite see how to move from there

Comment: Think of the singular vectors.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific ?